# How can we redirect user from login page to home page if user is logged in WordPress?

Tags: login

I have just installed WordPress locally in my computer and run the website successfully.
I want to achieve following: when logged-in user tries to access wp-login.php or register page, it should be automatically redirected to home page.

I have spent several hours on web, but could no come up with solution neither was I able to find appropriate WordPress plugin.

My question is: why does WordPress function this way? how can we change this behavior as natively as simply as possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the current page being loaded through the $pagenow global variable. Both login and registration is handled through wp-login.php. Adding this to the functions.php of your theme should work:

```
<?php

add_action('init', function () {

    if ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' && is_user_logged_in() && (!isset($_GET['action']) || $_GET['action'] !== 'logout')) {

        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;

    }

});
```

**EDIT:** Added a check to allow logging out and clarified where to put this code.

Comment: Thanks. Also, could you please, tell in which file should i place above script? Also, i have previously tried this, but when i use the above code and press logout button, it does not logout anymore, instead it  redirects to home page. is it possible to correct this?

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili You're right, this would make logging out impossible so I've added a check to see if the user is trying to log out. I also should've mentioned this should be placed in the functions.php of the (child-)theme you are using. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I also did that myself. we both came up with same sollution i guess. I am going to accept your answer.

Comment: I am hoping this approach doesnot ahve any downsides

Comment: Thanks, be mindful of the place you've put it in your answer: That file can be overridden by WordPress updates (best to assume it will every time you update), so putting it in the theme or a child theme is less hassle.

Comment: @Patriot @TornikeShavishvili If I am not mistaken, this code would block admin users as well. Is this the desired effect? If not, you might want to check users capabilities/roles with `current_user_can()` function. Here you can find the official developer documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/

Comment: @CelsoBessa I currently have one user with Administrator role, but it is not blocked with this modified code. Could you please mention exactly which roles and which functionality might get blocked?

Answer (score 1):

i modified @Patriot code.

I was able to achieve desired functionality with following code:
I added this code to `\wp-includes\functions.php` at the and of file.

It not as clean is i wished, but it works.

If someone sees any possible issues with this approach, please inform us

```
add_action('init', function() {

    if ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'wp-login.php' && is_user_logged_in()) {
        
        $defLoginPageActions = array(
            //'confirm_admin_email',
            //'postpass',
            'logout',
            //'lostpassword',
            //'retrievepassword',
            //'resetpass',
            //'rp',
            //'register',
            //'checkemail',
            //'confirmaction',
            //'login',
            WP_Recovery_Mode_Link_Service::LOGIN_ACTION_ENTERED,
        );
        $loginPageAction = isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

         
        if(!in_array( $loginPageAction, $defLoginPageActions)){  
            wp_redirect(home_url());
            exit;
        } 

    }
 
});
```